# saving a urlconnection file to google cloud storage from app engine java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am downloading a file (mp3) from a url and want to save it to google cloud storage via my appengine java app.  I can download the file and it plays fine, but when I save it to GCS and then play it it sounds funny and has a different file size.  The code I am using is:

```
        URL url = new URL(link);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.setConnectTimeout(20000);
        connection.setReadTimeout(20000);
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        GcsFileOptions options = new GcsFileOptions.Builder().acl("public-read").build();
        GcsOutputChannel fileChannel = gcsService.createOrReplace(new GcsFilename("ivrfiles", propertyId.toString()+"Address.mp3"), options);
        ObjectOutputStream oout = new ObjectOutputStream(Channels.newOutputStream(fileChannel));
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int n = - 1;
        while ( (n = input.read(buffer)) != -1)
        {
            oout.write(buffer, 0, n);
        }
        oout.close();
```

I tried to add .contentEncoding(connection.getContentEncoding()) to the FileOptionsBuilder, but connection.getContentEncoding() was returning null so that didn't work.

Is there something that I am doing wrong, maybe with setting the encoding?

If it matters, the file created via this code can be seen here: 
http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/ivrfiles%2F20001Address.mp3

The working file downloaded through chrome is here:http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/ivrfiles%2Fgen%20%282%29.mp3

I find the bad file has the same five bytes randomly inserted in every now and then, but I don't know why...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be using `new ObjectOutputStream`. Remove that from your code and just write to the output stream you obtain from `Channels.newOutputStream` directly.